# Why @import SCSS causes 'show' action in Rails 3.2?

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sass

Here is the issue:

A jquery-ui SCSS file is imported in `application.css.scss`:

```
@import "jquery-ui"
```

Also in the `application.html.erb`, there is a line about jquery-ui.scss:

```
 <link href="jquery-ui.scss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/ >
```

File `_jquery-ui.scss` is saved under `/app/assets/stylesheets/`. We noticed in our Rails 3.2 app for `create` something, the rails app fires up `show` action after `create` action. If we remove both `@import` and `<link ...>` from 2 files above, then the 'show' action disappears. Here is the content of `params` for the `show` action:

[image].

What I don't understand is why the @import of a SCSS file causes the Rails app to fire up `show` in `create`. This `show` causes my Rails app malfunctioning. Any idea about this behavior and fixing?

Comment: Using online CDN jquery-ui.css is a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the culprit is that you're referencing the `.scss` file and not the generated `.css`, so this formulation would be a little more correct:

```
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/ >
```

However, you should be using [Rails' Asset Tag Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#asset-tag-helpers) in your erb file:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery-ui" %>
```

That way, the Rails asset pipeline can do the work for you of outputting the correct file name.